# Youtube Video Embedding - Displaying None

Tags: html, css, youtube, embedding

I am working with this page here:
http://www.kineticoriginsofrhythm.com/

and I can't seem to get the video to show up. I think I am missing a step.

The Video Shows up Here but not on index splash JS.
http://www.kineticoriginsofrhythm.com/splash.asp

Im using this Tech:
http://jsfiddle.net/JjvzT/

Anyone know?

Thanks Very Much,
James

Comment: Please show some of the relevant code here so the question can have value for future viewers as well.

Comment: or on the link, can't even see the embed code.

Comment: Please Re-Read the OP as I have added some information. TY for your help btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're suppose to have some sort of video on the "splash" page?

I've looked over your code and you have zero videos being embedded in your HTML.  All I see is this: `<div id="video"></div>`.

YouTube will generate the code you need.  You should just copy/paste the embed code they generate for you in that location.

Long story short, you have no video showing up on your site because there's no video on your site.  If you're working with some sort of website form where you insert HTML code, it's possible that tool might be stripping out your code.

---

Here's some extra help.

Your splash HTML is:

```
<div id="splash" class="videosplash">
    <div id="homeButton"><a href="index.asp">Kinetic Origins of Rhythm Home Page</a></div>
    <div id="video"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <span><div id="enter"><a href="#">Enter KOR</a></div></span>
</div>
```

You've only got one video on your YouTube account so I'll assume you want that video to be linked.  Go to that video's page and click on the "embed" link to get the embed code.  Here it is for simplicity:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="853" height="510" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/H53rvFBqToA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</iframe>
```

You can probably play with the "width" and "height" attributes in the iframe tag to get it to fit the way you want it to on your page.  But you bascially want to copy/paste that "iframe" code into your "div" tag with the "video" id.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're trying to load that, but I always try and implement youtube videos with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).  Seems to fix cross-compatibility errors/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing you video id from your link.  You have just specified a link to your channel and not included an id.  Your link should look some like:

http://www.youtube.com/v/ZcEP3zVdYiM

Here is how I implement it:

```
<object width="534" height="318">
    <param name="WMode" value="transparent"></param>
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZcEP3zVdYiM"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZcEP3zVdYiM&hl=en_GB&fs=1&" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="534" height="318"></embed>
</object>
```

You can literally copy and paste the above code into your site and all you'll need to do is change the video links.  And the width/height if they aren't the same size :o)

Comment: Please Re-Read the OP as I have added some information. TY for your help btw.

Comment: @Varazi: You have the correct `embed` link in an `iframe` in your `Splash` page.  Copy that link into your other page and it will work.